# Pass RealmQuery object to Activity using Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, realm

I have an `Activity` that creates a `RealmQuery<E>` and I need to pass this query to another `Activity` to execute it. I can't do this using an `Intent` as the object I'm trying to pass is not parcelable. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can't you just pass raw variables in a bundle and build the query in the second activity?

Comment: You can use a shared object to save the query and access it from the other activity. You need an object that is always alive while the app is running. So it can be the Application class or some Manager instance.. Or..... what @ErnestZamelczyk said.....

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk I have too many variables and a huge method to build the Query, that's why I do this in separate Activities

Comment: You can see my answer. Even if you have many variables, the best way to do that is intent extra.

Comment: @HedShafran that's great except it'll be an NPE if app comes back from background after slightly longer amount of time and you're not on a Pixel (4 GB RAM)

Answer (score 0):

Passing data back and forth `Activity` can be achieved with Intent Extra.

You can simply do the following

First `Activity`
Firstly obtain your data into variable its datatype

```
String uid = myModel.getUid();
```

Sending data to `ChefProfile` class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChefProfile.class);
intent.putExtra(ChefProfile.EXTRA_USER_ID, uid);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now let get the data from Intent since it has arrived to the calling activity

This is `Chef_Profile` class.
Firstly, we have to create a constant field for the data arrived.

```
private static final String EXTRA_USER_KEY = "uid";

//Here we obtain the data sent from first activity and extract it into userId
userId = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_USER_KEY);
if (userId == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must pass EXTRA_POST_KEY");
}
```

Comment: My problem is that it is not possible to do this to pass a RealmQuery object, this throws an error because this object is not Parcelable. I guess I'll just pass all the variables as someone mentioned. Thanks anyways

Comment: What you have to do is to get the `id` of the data in `database`, use `intent extra` to send that id to another `activity`, then query the `data` again from whatever `database` you are using. It is not a good programing practice to be sending big data to another `activity` back and forth. Please stick to convention.